# Windows and vmware-unity-helper

Tags: windows-7, vmware-workstation

I'm running VMWare Workstation 7 and I want to use the "vmware-unity-helper.exe" utility.  Does this utility work in windows?  I've found several articles that say that it does not work with VM Workstation 6.5 but nothing on 7.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this [article](http://av-school.com/article/a-41.html).

I tested it by using Windows 7 as host and Windows 2000 as guest system with VMware Player 3.1.2. Then entered Unity manually and drag the shortcut of my application from the virtual start-menu to my Desktop. The shortcut works well as soon as my virtual pc was started.